# passing gradient with torch.autograd.backward()

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I'm trying to obtain the gradient of loss with respect to combine. The function critic is implemented separately. Without the combine, loss=critic(p) works perfectly with loss.backward(), so my issue is somewhere else. How can I troubleshoot an issue like this?

```
def ogp(p: Tensor, cp: Tensor, q: Tensor, cq: Tensor, critic: Callable[[Tensor], Tensor]) -> Tensor:
    p.requires_grad = True
    q.requires_grad = True
    eps = torch.randint(0, 1, p.shape, dtype = torch.float32)
    eps.requires_grad = True
    combine = eps * p + (1.0-eps) * q
    combine.retain_grad()
    loss = critic(combine)
    loss.retain_grad() 
    torch.autograd.backward(loss, grad_tensors = torch.ones_like(loss), retain_graph=True, create_graph = True)
    grad =  eps * p.grad + (1.0-eps) * q.grad
    norms = (torch.norm(grad) - 1.0)**2
    return norms
```

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Comment: I would like all variables to contribute to the gradient, but from the results it seems like this isn't the case. 
P.S: I'm pretty new with autograd and the ressources are pretty confusing, I'm looking for the best way to troubleshoot this.